# How to set validation for UNIQUE fields in MongoDB, Vuejs?

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to MongoDB and Vuejs. I'm not sure if it is possible that I was trying to set validation for Unique value, but somehow it does not work.

My defined schema from back-end:

```
const uuid = require("uuid");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let informationSchema = new Schema ({
    _id: {type: String, default: uuid.v1},
    firstName: {                                    
        type: String, required:true, trim: true, unique: true
    },
    lastName: {                                     
        type: String, required:true, trim: true, unique: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('informations', informationSchema)
```

My action form in Vuejs from Front-end:

```
<template>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="text-center">Create Name</h3>
            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmitForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name.firstName" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name.lastName" required>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger mt-3">Create</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: {
                   firstName: '',
                   lastName: ''  
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            handleSubmitForm() {
                let apiURL = 'http://localhost:3000/name';
                
                axios.post(apiURL, this.student).then(() => {
                    console.log(res)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }
        }
           
    }
</script>
```

My 1st inserted data: `[{"firstName":"ABC", "lastName": "DCF"}]`
I want to insert the 2nd one with data : firstName = "ABC", but last name = "XYZ". The error for validation occured because of validation (Unique) set in the defined schema from back-end).

My expected output:

Is there any possible ways to do:

1. If I insert the 1st data, it will work.
2. If I insert the 2nd data same as the 1st data, the error for validation will occur.
3. If I insert the 3rd data that is different from lastName only, it will work.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Mongo and Vue are completly separated, there is no relation.

Answering your question, the validation fail because you are telling mongo "Set `firstName` and `lastName` as unique fields". But not "Set these fields unique TOGETHER". So when you add a firstname, the second attemp try to add an existing `firstName` and fails.

So you can create a unique index:

```js
informationSchema.index({ firstName: 1, lastName: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

And remove `unique` constraint in the schema.